# How can I compare check if a char value is equal to a given value in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, char, equality

Could someone help me with my if-statement so it checks if the variable `a` contains the lowercase letter "e"? Pretend that the variable `a` gets random values every time the program runs.

```
public static void check(char a){
    if(/*Code here*/){
        System.out.println("if");
    }else{
        System.out.println("else");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `if(a == 'a')`?

Comment: lol i am so stupid, i was using " "... I knew it couldnt be that hard but I just couldnt figure it out. Thank you so much Tim.